# Translate "New Moon on Monday" to Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

What would be the correct translation of the song title "New Moon on Monday" to Latin? Word for word with the same structure as English seems like it would be something like "Nova Luna in [dies Lunae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_the_days_of_the_week#Greco-Roman_tradition)", although I don't know if I'm using the right gender and case, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion *nova luna in dies lunae* is "new moon into Mondays".
It is grammatically valid, but does not mean what you want.

A new moon would be *luna nova* or *nova luna*.
Latin typically puts the adjective last, but it is not a hard rule.

Monday is *dies lunae*, literally "day of the moon".
When you decline this, you only change *dies* ("day") and leave *lunae* ("of the moon") untouched.
A time is usually expressed in Latin with a plain ablative without any prepositions, and that would be the only grammatical choice here.
Therefore "on Monday" would be *die lunae*.

The most direct and prosaic way to say "new moon on Monday" is ***luna nova die lunae***.
This also looks nice as the moons frame the rest of the phrase.
You can also put the moons next to each other: ***die lunae luna nova***.

If you use *interlunium* for new moon instead, it just replaces *luna nova* in the expression.
While *interlunium* is classically preferable, it might be less clear a concept in modern use for most readers than *luna nova*.

Comment: Ahh, I see! What I had originally was then something like, "New moon, Monday", rather than "New moon _on_ Monday".

Comment: I am not sure if "luna nova" is ever used in (classical) Latin. I know interlunium.

Comment: @fdb I have seen *luna nova*, but not in classical Latin. For the sake of clear communication and in the absence of a specified era, I would go with *luna nova*.

Comment: @Adam More precisely, what you had is "new moon into Mondays". Whether that can mean anything sensible is another question...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would this be if _interlunium_ was used, and does it mean "new moon" itself, or just "[time of the new moon](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/interlunium)"?

Comment: @Adam I updated the answer.

Comment: If you want to be really archaic, the new moon was originally _pridie Kalendas_, but that gained a different meaning when they got rid of the lunar calendar.

Comment: @Draconis Yeah, that'd only work in a special context. I would read it as "on the last day of the month" without considering any relation to the phase of the moon.